# Storing words of specific file in 2D Array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, file-handling

Struggling to store the words in a 2D Array, when I use **char** It works fine but when I use the logic below for storing **string** that's where I got confused

**Code:**

```
string word;
int rows ,column;
string arr[10][20];
 fstream myFile("name.txt"); 

  while(myFile>>word)
   {
   arr[rows][column]=word;
    }
```

Here I'm stuck that whats the algorithm for differentiation b/w rows and columns.

**name.txt:**

```
    It's steve 
    Studying CPP
    and steve loves cooking
```

Also, I want to display occurrences of this file as 2D-Array once I find the differentiation Algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, I think you forgot to initialize `rows` and `column`. But aside from that, `string`s manage the character array on their own, so you don't need a 2D array for them, but a simple 1D one.

Like so:

```
string word;
int rows = 0;
string arr[10];
fstream myFile("name.txt"); 

while(myFile>>word)
{
   arr[rows] = word;
   rows++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `std::vector` instead of array because `std::vector` is a variable size container and you don't always know how many elements the input.txt file contains. The complete working program [below](https://onlinegdb.com/37NfSEgdM) shows how to achieve what you want using **2D `std::vector`**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include<fstream>
int main() {
    std::string line, word;

    
    std::ifstream inFile("input.txt");
    
    //create/use a std::vector instead of builit in array 
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> vec;
    
    if(inFile)
    {
        while(getline(inFile, line, '\n'))        
        {
            //create a temporary vector that will contain all the columns
            std::vector<std::string> tempVec;
            
            
            std::istringstream ss(line);
            
            //read word by word 
            while(ss >> word)
            {
                //std::cout<<"word:"<<word<<std::endl;
                //add the word to the temporary vector 
                tempVec.push_back(word);
            
            }      
            
            //now all the words from the current line has been added to the temporary vector 
            vec.emplace_back(tempVec);
        }    
    }
    
    else 
    {
        std::cout<<"file cannot be opened"<<std::endl;
    }
    
    inFile.close();
    
    //lets check out the elements of the 2D vector so the we can confirm if it contains all the right elements(rows and columns)
    for(std::vector<std::string> &newvec: vec)
    {
        for(const std::string &elem: newvec)
        {
            std::cout<<elem<<" ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
    
    /*another way to print out the elements of the 2D vector would be as below 
    for(int row = 0; row < vec.size(); ++row)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < vec.at(row).size(); ++col)
        {
            std::cout<<vec.at(row).at(col)<<" ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
    */
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/37NfSEgdM). At the end of my program i have printed out the elements of the **2d vector** so that we can confirm if it contains all the elements correctly.